# reactjs and d3v4 npm install not recognizing common functions?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I have started a new react application - and started to install d3v4 and a basic pie chart - but I am now getting scaleOrdinal() errors and a d3.arc() error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'arc' of undefined"

```
            var arc = d3.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius - 10)
                .innerRadius(innerradius);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'arc' of undefined"

This error is because of undefined d3 object. You have installed d3 but not imported/required d3 in your file like so

> var d3 = require("d3");

Or if you are using ES6 modules import

> import * as d3 from "d3";

Comment: I imported it at the top like this? - import d3 from 'd3';

Comment: ah needs to be like this -- import * as d3 from "d3";